# Can the spin connection defind on an orthonormal frame be non-metric compatible?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, reference-frames

In the (holonomic) coordinate frame {$\partial_\mu$} with the affine connection $\Gamma^\alpha_{~\beta \gamma}$ and a generic metric $g_{\mu \nu}$, the manifold can acquire both **torsion** $T_{\alpha \beta \gamma}=\Gamma_{\alpha \beta \gamma}-\Gamma_{\alpha \gamma \beta}$ as well as **non-metricity** $Q_{\alpha \beta \gamma}=\nabla_{\alpha}g_{\beta \gamma}$.

I wanted to study non-metricity but using a different frame, namely an **orthonormal frame** of tetrads $e^a_{\mu}$ where the basis of tangent space $e^a=e^a_\mu dx^\mu$ is always orthonormal (with respect to Minkowski):
$$ <e^a,e^b>_g=\eta^{ab}$$

*My question is then the following: in this new frame, where the "perceived metric" is the Minkowski metric, can there be non-metricity?*

So far this is what I believe but I am unsure:
We have two different connections:

a) The connection in the coordinate frame $\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu \nu}$, where there can be torsion and non-metricity.

b)The connection in the bundle of orthonormal frame, denoted as $w_\mu^{ab}$, which is metric compatible because the metric is Minkowski. There can be torsion.

Now if we want to make a) and b) compatible, this gives the "tetrad postulate". And the information previously encoded in the non-metricity tensor in the coordinate frame is now hidden in the fact that the tetrad basis is not holonomic: $[e^a,e^b]\neq 0$.

Is this correct?

Thank you :)